# a trigonometric inequality in one variable, with sine and cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I seek ideas about proving a simple inequality:

$$
x+\cos x - \frac{\pi}{2}\sin x \geq 0 \qquad (x \geq 0)
$$

A numerical plot indicates that the function $f(x)$ on the left does attain a minimum value of zero at just one point $x=a$. Clearly $a < 1+\frac{\pi}{2}$. Beyond that it would be nice to use basic calculus, but $f(x)$ is such that the equations $f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)=0$ are both transcendental.

Comment: $a={\pi\over 2}$ . I think you can get to your result by simply studying $f$ on $[0,1+{\pi\over 2}]$ as above $1+{\pi\over 2}$ the inequality is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>\pi$ it's obvious,

but for $0\leq x\leq\pi$ there is $x_{\min}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, which kills this inequality.